# Get javascript highcharts to render inside a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3

Title is pretty self-explanatory.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/) with the popover and the highcharts js code. Chart only shows if you move targeted div outside the popover.

```
<a id="demo" href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
    $('#demo').popover();
});
```

Is anyone able to get the chart to render INSIDE the popover?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally its working , Please refer [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/6/)

```
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: "<div id='container' style='min-width: 300px;display:none;
    height: 200px; margin: 0'> <div id='Austin' style='width: 300px; height:
    200px;'></div></div>",
   html: true
   })
  .click(function() {
    var chart_data = getChartData();
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart( chart_data );
    $('#container').show();
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle with working popover with chart  [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/d491945o/2/)

```
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: $('#container').html(),
    html: true
    }).click(function() {
     $(this).popover('show');
    });
```

or simply you can call by its id as well like below

```
 $('#demo').popover({
 content: $('#container').html(),
 html: true
 }) ;
```

Comment: Looks nice, but the data isn't showing properly? There should be several lines, like so: ([updated with div outside](http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/4/))

Comment: You should increase width height of the highchart container div

Comment: Ok ,you should make containers hidden by default... See my fiddle

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/d491945o/2/  use this  $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: $('#container').html(),
    html: true
    }).click(function() {
     $(this).popover('show');
    });

Comment: It doesn't matter how large I make the div, I still see no data: http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/5/

Are you seeing the data? I tried in several web browsers and it's still a blank chart. I see the chart (which is a great first step) but there's no data in that chart no matter how small or large the div is.

Comment: I agree, I realize your issue. after calling inside popover chart is not showing.I am fixing this

Comment: great, thanks for taking a look, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397246/how-to-show-a-google-chart-in-popover-in-html5) is one method someone tried to get data to show up in popover, if it helps at all.

Comment: @Austin regret for delay, I just got time to fix that.Plz see http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/6/