# Highcharts in a modal window on click

Tags: jquery, meteor, highcharts, meteor-blaze, bootbox

This might be slightly basic for the people here, but I'd be glad if you could help. I want to be able to open a [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) in a modal window on clicking an element. How would I do that? I'm using [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com) and was wondering if this is achievable with/without [BootboxJS](http://bootboxjs.com/).

Comment: you can do it with bootstrap / bootbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below code :

```
 $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
 content: "<div id='container' style='min-width: 300px;display:none;
 height: 200px; margin: 0'> <div id='Austin' style='width: 300px; height:
 200px;'></div></div>",
 html: true
 })
  .click(function() {
  var chart_data = getChartData();
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart( chart_data );
  $('#container').show();
  });
```

see working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d491945o/6/)
and same kind of question [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599938/get-javascript-highcharts-to-render-inside-a-bootstrap-popover/32607677#32607677)

Answer (score 0):

For Highchart and BootboxJS , already have package support them in meteor

https://atmospherejs.com/maazalik/highcharts

https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootboxjs

maybe you post more your code to us to help you coding out.